# How to bind my custom component (directive) to an arbitrary model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

What I want to achieve is to be able to to bind an angular model to a custom component like this:

```
<my-text model="myModel" field="myField" default-value="n/a"></my-text>
```

This is supposed to create an edit component for `myModel`'s `myField` field which has a `default-value` of `n/a`.

The template for my component is rather simple:

```
<input type="text" value="{{defaultValue}}" ng-model="model.field"/>
```

and my directive looks like this:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MyFormComponents').directive('myText', [function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl : 'templates/myTextTemplate.html',
            scope : {
                model : '=',
                field : '@',
                defaultValue : '@'
            },
            link : function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            },
            controller : function($scope) {
            }
        };
    }])
})(angular);
```

The problem is that the `input` field is generated but there is no `default-value` in it, and if I type in something it does not propagate the value I typed to my model. There is no error message either. What am I doing wrong? If I do then what is the idiomatic way in Angular to achieve my goal?

If I try this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{defaultValue}}" ng-model="model.{{field}}"/>
```

I get a syntax error.

Comment: I think it might be better if you used ng-model directly with your directive. If you do that, you can use the ngModelCtrl inside your directive to modify the model value, including setting it to the attrs.defaultValue.

Comment: Can you link to an example or provide it as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way:

```
<input type="text" value="{{defaultValue}}" ng-model="model[field]"/>
```

Comment: This works but now I have another problem: if I type in anything the value of `defaultValue` changes to what I typed **and more importantly** my original `myModel` does not change only the `model` does in my directive. `defaultValue` is not supposed to change and the changes should be propagated to my original `myModel`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking try something like this:

```
.directive('myText', [function() {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'templates/myTextTemplate.html',
        link : function($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
                        if ($attributes.defaultValue) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($attributes.defaultValue); 
                            }
        },
        controller : function($scope) {
        }
    };
}])
```

And then:

```
<my-text ng-model="myModel.myField" default-value="n/a"></my-text>
```

The ngModelCtrl docs are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

You don't really need to bind those attributes into the scope unless you are going to use them in a view. That also creates unnecessary bindings - which later could cause performance problems.